# ReadProcessMemory Crashes Application When Trying to Read 32bit Integer From Another Process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process, readprocessmemory

I have been experimenting with various aspects of the Windows API and thought I would give process memory manipulation a try. Previously I had been trying to do this in native C++ using this method: [C++ - Get value of a particular memory address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298208/c-get-value-of-a-particular-memory-address)

However, this method does not work and I found a response somewhere on the Cplusplus forum that told me to use ReadProcessMemory. I found that WriteProcessMemory works just fine when attempting to edit values, but ReadProcessMemory either fails (returning error code 299) or crashes the application.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    LPVOID bytes;
    DWORD pid;
    SIZE_T *num_bytes_read;
    int temp;
    SIZE_T size = sizeof(temp);
    LPCVOID address = reinterpret_cast<int*>(0x404004);
    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, "C:\\Users\\Delkarix\\Desktop\\memory_edit_test.exe");
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);

    BOOL worked = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, address, bytes, size, num_bytes_read);
    cout << "ERROR: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    cout << "PROCESS: " << hProcess << endl;
    cout << "BYTES: " << bytes << endl;
    cout << "BASE ADDRESS: " << address << endl;
    cout << "FUNCTION SUCCESS: " << worked << endl;
    cout << "BYTES READ: " << *num_bytes_read << endl;
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}
```

I have noticed that the application crashes when the num_bytes_read variable is a pointer (the 5th parameter of ReadProcessMemory is the num_bytes_read variable) and it throws error 299 when it is not a pointer (the 5th parameter of ReadProcessMemory is the pointer to the num_bytes_read variable).

Here is the code for the memory_edit_test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int test = 6;
int main() {
    string input;
    cout << &test << endl; // Where I got the address 0x404004
    getline(cin, input);
    cout << test << endl; // Used to check the value against the one I got from ReadProcessMemory
    getline(cin, input);
}
```

How can I get ReadProcessMemory to succeed? Answers to similar questions on StackOverflow either do nothing or they just make the problem worse.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540400/error-299-on-readprocessmemory)

Comment: You should check if `OpenProcess` fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is very simple, third parameter to `ReadProcessMemory` is meant to point to a buffer, where the memory read will be written to. You just give it an unintialised pointer. Similar problem with the fifth parameter as well.

Your code should look something like this

```
int temp;
SIZE_T num_bytes_read;
BOOL worked = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, address, &temp, sizeof temp, &num_bytes_read);
```

Note third and fifth parameters are pointers **to already existing memory**. Declare a variable and use `&` to get its address.

Comment: Thank you so much! Solving this problem has taken so much time out of my day. Simple, straightforward, and just what I was looking for.