# ReadProcessMemory() Returning 0 ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, process

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

DWORD GetModuleBase(LPSTR lpModuleName, DWORD dwProcessId)
{
   MODULEENTRY32 lpModuleEntry = {0};
   HANDLE hSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwProcessId );

   if(!hSnapShot)
      return NULL;
   lpModuleEntry.dwSize = sizeof(lpModuleEntry);
   BOOL bModule = Module32First( hSnapShot, &lpModuleEntry );
   while(bModule)
   {
      if(!strcmp( lpModuleEntry.szModule, lpModuleName ) )
      {
         CloseHandle( hSnapShot );
         return (DWORDLONG)lpModuleEntry.modBaseAddr;
      }
      bModule = Module32Next( hSnapShot, &lpModuleEntry );
   }
   CloseHandle( hSnapShot );
   return NULL;
}


int main() {
    DWORD pID;
    DWORDLONG off1, off2;
    DWORDLONG baseAddress;
    char moduleName[] = _T("AoE2DE_s.exe");
    HWND hGameWindow;
    HANDLE pHandle;

    //Get Handles
    hGameWindow = FindWindow(NULL, "Age of Empires II: Definitive Edition");
    cout << "Game Window: " << hGameWindow << std::endl;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hGameWindow, &pID);
    cout << "Process ID: " << pID << std::endl;
    pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pID);

    cout << "Process Handle: " << std::hex << pHandle << std::endl;

    //Get Client Base Addy
    DWORDLONG clientBase = GetModuleBase(moduleName, pID);
    cout << "Client Base: " << clientBase << std::endl;
    ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPCVOID)(clientBase + 0x2BFCA18), &baseAddress, sizeof(DWORDLONG), NULL);
    DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
    cout << "Error: " << lastError << std::endl;
    cout << "Base Address: " << std::hex << baseAddress << std::endl;
    ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPCVOID)(baseAddress + 0x18), &off1, sizeof(DWORDLONG), NULL);
    cout << "After Offset 1: " << std::hex << off1 << std::endl;
    ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPCVOID)(off1 + 0x9230), &off2, sizeof(DWORDLONG), NULL);
    cout << "After Final Offset: " << off2 << std::endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

The error occurs on this line:
`ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPCVOID)(clientBase + 0x2BFCA18), &baseAddress, sizeof(DWORDLONG), NULL);`

Application output for debugging purposes:

```
Game Window: 0x1307c2
Process ID: 11988
Process Handle: 0xec
Client Base: cc640000
Error: 12b
Base Address: 0
After Offset 1: 401519
After Final Offset: 8
```

Not sure how it is failing here, I'm somewhat new to this. Everything else goes through perfectly without error's but fails on the first ReadProcessMemory() if someone can help bring the solution for this to light I would be grateful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 299 on ReadProcessMemory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540400/error-299-on-readprocessmemory)

Comment: I looked through that and it seems I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: In the code you don't check the return value of `ReadProcessMemory`. Only if it returns 0 you should use `GetLastError`.

Comment: Windows' error reporting has 2 simple rules: `1` **Always** check the return value(s). `2` Only call `GetLastError` under those documented conditions where it returns a meaningful value. You are violating both.

Comment: Am I not checking the return value on printing out the result on the next line? If that's not the return value then I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: How do you get the value of `0x2BFCA18`? it seems that the address you read is beyond the scope of the `pHandle` process. Try to use [`VirtualQueryEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualqueryex) to retrieves information about a range of pages within the virtual address space of a specified process. In addition, if the `pHandle` process is 64-bit and the sample process is 32-bit, you will get the error 0x12b as well.

Comment: The value `0x2BFCA18` is derived from Cheat Engine. Both processes are in 64-bit.

Comment: Try to use `VirtualQueryEx` to get that address `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION`, and check if `Protect` member contains `PAGE_NOACCESS`.

Answer (score 2):

ReadProcessMemory is defined like this:

```
BOOL ReadProcessMemory(
  HANDLE  hProcess,
  LPCVOID lpBaseAddress,
  LPVOID  lpBuffer,
  SIZE_T  nSize,
  SIZE_T  *lpNumberOfBytesRead
);
```

If it returns zero then there has been an error, and only in that case `GetLastError` will return a meaningfull error number.

So correct usage would be:

```
SIZE_T readBytes;
if (!ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPCVOID)(clientBase + 0x2BFCA18), &baseAddress, sizeof(DWORDLONG), &readBytes)) {
  DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
  cout << "ReadProcessMemory failed: Error: " << lastError << " read " << readBytes << std::endl;
}
else
{
  cout << "ReadProcessMemory succeeded"; << std::endl;
  cout << "Base Address: " << std::hex << baseAddress << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I ran it exactly as you stated and it is outputting the line ReadProcessMemory failed with error 12b (ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY)

Comment: The bytes read should differ from sizeof(DWORDLONG)